# Share a stylus sheet between packages

Tags: meteor

I've got an app broken into a handful of packages. Each of these packages has their own .styl sheet to style the components that specific package offers. Currently, these .styl sheets all rely on the same functions, mixins, and variables declared in the `variables.import.styl` that is in the `./client/styles` folder. I do this because if I change the `errorRed` color in the `variables.import.styl`, it changes the color across all packages.

To get access to those variables, at the top of each package's stylesheet, I have a `@import "./client/styles/variables.import"`. Alternatively, I could create a separate package for the stylus vars & then make that package a dependency in all the other packages. I don't love either option, but I suppose it's the price I pay to keep stylesheets separated by package. Anyone have a more elegant alternative?

It's worth noting that on the Meteor devel branch, my previous solution no longer works (stylus can't see folder above the package root). Regardless of whether this is fixed or not before the next version release, I know there's gotta be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Related question - I'd love to know a better way to import files other than via a relative path. I'm sick of writing `@inport '../../../../../css/imports/something`.

Comment: Absolute path from root (`./`) doesn't work for you?

Comment: I guess (as a last resort solution) you could fork the stylus package and add some custom code to always include your variables file? If you're using mquandalle:stylus the repo is https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-stylus

Comment: I believe that on the devel branch, you can do `@import {someones:package}/foo.styl` (with the curly braces) to import styles cross-package, or `@import {}/foo.styl` to import from your app. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4800.

Answer (score 0):

As of Meteor 1.2, this is now a feature working out of the box, for both stylus and less stylesheets.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/stylus#cross-packages-imports

In your `package.js` `Package.onUse` section, use `api.addFiles` to declare stylus sheets provided by this package :

```
api.addFiles('styles/package-sheet.styl', 'client', {isImport: true});
```

Notice the `isImport: true` option ?

Then in your main app master stylus stylesheet you can import a specific package (let's suppose it's named `my-username:mypackage`) sheet using this syntax :

```
@import '{my-username:my-package}/styles/package-sheet.styl'
```

Note that for importing sheets within your app you will also need to use this new syntax, without any package name :

```
@import '{}/client/styles/app-sheet.styl'
```

The previous syntax will no longuer work !

```
// the Meteor build tool will complain about not finding the sheet
@import 'client/styles/app-sheet.styl'
```